# Finding the probability mass function for the given CDF

Tags: probability

Given the CDF function of the random variable:
$
F_X(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    0, & x \leq 1  \\
    ax-0.1, & 1 <x\leq 4 \\
    1, & x > 4 
\end{cases}
$

Find the distribution function of the random variable X (PMF) depending on the parameter $a$ and discuss what values ​​the parameter $a$ can obtain? Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not sure about this but is not final value of CDF always 1 ?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: I mean if $f(x)$ is the cdf of $x$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 1$

Comment: I know this definition

Comment: He needs PDF from CDF

Comment: is it $a$ or $ax$ in the bracket

Comment: I correct sir F(a) is F(x)

Comment: This is not a valid CDF.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$$
f(x)=F'(x)=  \Bigg\{  
\begin{array}{rl}
0& if \ x\leq 1\\
a& if \ 1<x\leq 4\\
0&  if \ x>4
\end{array}
$$

Since total area below the graph is 1 we see that $a=1/3$.

[image]

Comment: so simple ?! - what can you say about the part:depending on the parameter a and discuss what values ​​the parameter a can obtain

Comment: hmm, is there $a$ or $x$ in the bracket and in $F(a)$?

Comment: before concluding that is $a$, or by the are that the graph gives

Comment: Isnt this pdf not satisfying the normalisation property? Also given cdf in question should be giving 1 as x tends to infinity? Please tell me, thanks!!

Comment: i didnt know how to conclude that $a=1/3$

Comment: Please unaccept my ansver since it is wrong, since your CDF is wrong